# An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

Tags: mysql, symfony, docker

I have a problem with docker and symfony to access mysql.

To try to query mysql by connecting to the php container:

> docker exec -it symfony_php bash

Then I execute the following command:

> bin/console doctrine:database:create

This is where I get the following error message:

> An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE [HY000] [2002] Connection refused

Here is the code of my "docker-compose.yml":

```
version: '3'
services:
    apache:
        container_name: symfony_apache
        build: .docker/apache
        ports:
            - "80:80"
        volumes:
            - .docker/config/vhosts:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled
            - .:/home/www/symfony
        depends_on:
          - php

    mysql:
        container_name: symfony_mysql
        image: mysql
        ports:
            - "3306:3306"   
        volumes:
            - .docker/data/db:/var/lib/mysql
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
            MYSQL_DATABASE: sf4
            MYSQL_USER: sf4
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: sf4

    php:
        container_name: symfony_php
        build: .docker/php
        volumes:
            - .:/home/www/symfony
        depends_on:
            - mysql 

    phpmyadmin:
        container_name: symfony_phpmyadmin
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
        ports:
            - "8080:80"
        environment:
            PMA_HOST: mysql
            PMA_PORT: 3306
        links:
            - mysql
```

Here is the code of my .env:

> DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:root@127.0.0.1:3306/s4

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Did you try to use the internal identifier as mysql host?

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:root@symfony_mysql:3306/s4
DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:root@mysql:3306/s4
```

I don't think 127.0.0.1 works from within the container.

You also could try to use your 'external' IP or URL, as you have exposed port 3306 already.

Comment: phpmyadmin is using mysql as host, so this might be the correct hostname.

Comment: Yes it works well with the following line:
DATABASE_URL = mysql: // root: root symfony_mysql: 3306 / s4

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 5):

use this command to get the ip adress

```
docker inspect mysql | grep IPAddress
```

then for example:

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:@the ip adress:3306/dbname?serverVersion=5.7
DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:@172.17.0.3:3306/test?serverVersion=5.7
```

or instead of the the ip adress make the name of the container

Comment: I also had to change `mysql` to `mysqli`. Thanks, this helped a lot

Answer (score 0):

You’re trying to connect to `root:root`, but your user is `sf4`. Try:

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://sf4:sf4@127.0.0.1:3306/s4
```

Also try connecting from the command line, to make sure that it is actually working.

Edit: Just realised that `Connection refused` is normally when it’s not running, not a user/password error. Check that MySQL is running.

Comment: I tried to connect to mysql in my docker container: symfony_mysql with the following command:    
docker exec -it symfony_mysql bash
Then:
mysql

That's what it showed me:
root @ 099870f6d0fd: / # mysql
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

So I typed the password: "root" and then I had access to mysql without problem. So I think at this level there is no problem.

Answer (score 0):

My problem is the Docker network didn't work.

I've recreated Docker network and all containers and it helped me.

Example that removes containers and the network and recreates them.

```bash
docker-compose down 
docker-compose up -d
```

Answer (score -3):

Please check if XAMPP is working correctly