# Symfony 5 : An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE [HY000] [2002] Connection refused

Tags: php, symfony5

I had a problem with symfony and this was linked to the fact that Symfony was using now postgressSQL by default instead of MySQL.

As I want to use MySQL I changed the following in .env

```
# DATABASE_URL="mysql://root:@127.0.0.1:3306/evergirls?serverVersion=5.7"
DATABASE_URL="mysql://root:@127.0.0.1:5432/evergirls?serverVersion=13&charset=utf8"
```

However when I try to run the command :

```
php bin/console doctrine:database:create
```

I get the following message :

> In AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 112:
>
> An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connexion
> could have been created as the targetted computer rejected it.
> (translated from french)

And so on ... same message repeated for some other lines.

The connexion data (username and password) are correct.

As I found on an other post I tried to change the port :

> @127.0.0.1:3306

by

> symfony_mysql:3306/s4

and by

> mysql:3306/s4

like suggested in this post : [An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52501969/an-exception-occurred-in-driver-sqlstatehy000-2002-connection-refused)

Any idea how to solve it ?

Answer (score 1):

What is the port of your mysql server ?3306 or 5432 ? 
Be sure mysql server is running.

Otherwhise, you can test with:

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://root@localhost:3306/evergirls
```