# Symfony 5 : SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] refusing connection

Tags: mysql, doctrine, symfony5

I aam trying to create a new doctrine database using Symfony 5.

Recently Symfony changed using mysql by default to using pstgreSQL.

As I want to use mysql I changed the comment in .env from :

```
# DATABASE_URL="mysql://db_user:db_password@127.0.0.1:3306/db_name?serverVersion=5.7"
DATABASE_URL="postgresql://db_user:db_password@127.0.0.1:5432/db_name?serverVersion=13&charset=utf8"
```

to

```
# DATABASE_URL="mysql://root:@127.0.0.1:3306/mywebsite?serverVersion=5.7"
DATABASE_URL="mysql://root:d@127.0.0.1:5432/mywebsite?serverVersion=13&charset=utf8"
```

in other words I just changed postgresql to mysql and commented what needs to be commented.

However when I run

```
php bin/console doctrine:database:create
```

I get the following error :

> In AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 112:
> An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection
> has been established as the target computer rejected it (translated
> from french)

I found the following posts :
[An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52501969/an-exception-occurred-in-driver-sqlstatehy000-2002-connection-refused)

and

In AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 112:

An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddr
esses: getaddrinfo failed: Hte inconnu.

in short both tells me to change "127.0.0.1" by "mysql"

but when running as such I get this error

In AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 112:

> An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]
> php_network_getaddr     esses: getaddrinfo failed: Hte inconnu.

What mistake did I do or what did I miss?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I found a very simple solutionthat will seems obvious for experienced dev but not for beginners that is never talked about.

just change the # at the beginning of the first line

```
# DATABASE_URL="mysql://root:@127.0.0.1:3306/mywebsite?serverVersion=5.7"
DATABASE_URL="mysql://root:d@127.0.0.1:5432/mywebsite?serverVersion=13&charset=utf8"
```

to the second line

```
DATABASE_URL="mysql://root:@127.0.0.1:3306/mywebsite?serverVersion=5.7"
 # DATABASE_URL="mysql://root:d@127.0.0.1:5432/mywebsite?serverVersion=13&charset=utf8"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can found documentation here https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine1/en/latest/manual/introduction-to-connections.html

In your config the port 5432 is not default port of Mysql

Try

```
  DATABASE_URL="mysql://root:d@127.0.0.1:3306/mywebsite?serverVersion=13&charset=utf8"
```