# php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine, doctrine-migrations

Hello When i use `php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate` i have this error:

```
In ExceptionConverter.php line 103:

  An exception occurred in the driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused  

In Exception.php line 30:

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused  

In Driver.php line 28:

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
```

`DATABASE_URL="mysql://root:@127.0.0.1:3306/db_docker?serverVersion=10.4.22-MariaDB"`

What does this error mean? How can I fix it?

Comment: where are you running this command? from docker container? probably duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52501969/an-exception-occurred-in-driver-sqlstatehy000-2002-connection-refused

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DATABASE_URL="mysql://root:root@127.0.0.1:55000/dbanem?serverVersion=mariadb-10.4.11&charset=utf8mb4"
```

Change 55000 to your port.